# Scaffold EF Core - Change Table Name

Tags: ef-core-8.0

I am generating my dbContext and model file through the PMC with the command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=xxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Serialisatie;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir Data -Outputdir Models/Generated -ContextNamespace Serialisatie.Data -Namespace Serialisatie.Models -NoOnConfiguring -t tblSerialisatieOrders -Force
```

This is working fine, the only thing I want to change is the table name.  tblSerialisatieOrders should rename to Order, but I can't find a way to do this.

Actual Result:
[image]

Requested Result: (Changed this manually now)
[image]